# Assembly compl 32 bit, 8 bit

Tags: assembly, 32-bit

I am looking at some assembly code and I see:

```
cmpl $0x1d32, -0x4(%ebp)
```

Since -0x4(%ebp) is 1 byte, it obviously cannot store the other value (7474) in it. Thus, when would this code show them as equal? Would it only compare the most/least significant byte of the immediate value or is there some sort of hidden word extension?

Comment: Who says that `-0x4(%ebp)` is 1 byte? `l` suffix in `cmpl` says clearly that it's a long, that is, 4 bytes (32 bits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-0x4(%ebp)` is an address, it doesn't have any associated size. The `l` suffix in the instruction specifies the size as a 32 bit integer (`long`). Thus the processor will fetch 4 bytes starting with the given address, and use that as the operand interpreting it in little-endian byte order (that is starting with the least significant byte).